# Install full version of visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation

I'm having trouble installing a full version of visual studio. I had first installed the evaluation copy of 2012 and then got a full paid version afterward, but visual studio is stuck on the evaluation copy, I've tried to uninstall the the evaluation copy and then install the new one but it did not work. How can I install the full paid version?

Thanks,
James

Comment: Follow the instructions in the http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2771441 and then try to install the full-paid version.


  [1]: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2771441

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same problem before with my visual studio. I came accross this site, [microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2771441) please check it out. I hope you get it figured out soon.

Regards.